# Database design - storing equivalence

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing the relational database for a system that stores information about certain types of products, retailers and suppliers for the retailers.

Some of the suppliers sell the same products - however, they don't have a standard for identifying the products which means supplier A might have a product with id 618261 that is equivalent to supplier B's product 007162.

The problem is, I don't want to store the same product multiple times for different suppliers. Currently, I have the following tables:

**equivalence**

- supplier1_id
- supplier2_id
- supplier1_product_id
- supplier2_product_id

**product**

- id (generated)
- supplier_id
- supplier_product_id

This seems like a bad idea. Whenever something is inserted into 'product',

1. 'equivalence' must be queried to find every equivalence
2. 'product' must be queried to find if equivalent products are already stored
3. if equivalents are not found, the product can be inserted

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an uncommon scenario, different suppliers many times will have their own SKU numbers for a common product. Additionally, a product may have different manufacturers each with their own part number. But let's look just at the suppliers.

In plain English, a supplier may supply many products and a product may be available from many suppliers. This many-to-many relationship is maintained via a cross or intersection table. If you think about it, the SKU number is not an attribute of the Product entity or of the Supplier entity. Instead, it is an attribute of the relationship. Yes, relationships may have attributes just as any entity.

```
create table ProductSupplier(
  ProductID   int  not null references Products( ID ),
  SupplierID  int  not null references Suppliers( ID ),
  UnitPrice   currency not null,
  SKU         varchar
);
```

The UnitPrice could well be a list of per-unit prices that would vary according to the volume ordered. Thus it would likely be in another table -- I've added it here to show an additional supplier-product relationship attribute.

Again in plain English, a tuple from this table says, "*this* product from *this* supplier has *this* SKU number."